# Personalizar boton de inicio de sesion de facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

Estoy creando un inicio de sesion con facebook, y todo va excelente, excepto a que odio el boton de Facebook y quisiera poner el mio propio, asi como esta en stackoverflow.

Este es el codigo de mi boton de facebook

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">Ingresar con Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Y este es mi boton personal

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Ingresar con Facebook</button>
```

como hago?

Comment: Saludos Anthony, por curiosidad ¿Has leído la documentación de Facebook?

Comment: he leido y he intentado, pero sin resultado exitoso

Comment: Excelente, edita tu pregunta agregando todos esos intentados, así demuestras que algo has querido hacer. En estos lares valoramos mucho los intentos, así dan más ganas de responder :D